# Name must exclude only numeric values and punctuation marks, space. PYTHON

Tags: python

Is there any built-in option or any other way to make a rule, where answer to the input may be only String or string+numeric value without punctuation marks/space. So that will look like.

```
Insert first name:  …
… name: 5363737 - not allowed
… name: Bird1 ! - not allowed
… name: Bird1 - allowed
```

Comment: have you tried regex in python?

Comment: I in my first semester at Univ. We haven't learned that yet. This exercise is part of my bigger homework. But I will look into regex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two possible options ("pseudo code" below):

**The ugly**

Is first name an instance of a numeric type? If it is, discard. If it is not, then: for char in name, is char a whitespace? If it is, discard.

**The good**

Does name match a regex of numbers or does name match a regex in which there is a whitespace? If that's the case, discard.

I don't have time right now for implementing them, but that would be the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You want check input from user? If you want this, You can use `for` loop and then check conditions with `if` . Its simplest form what is immediately thought. For check conditions look in string method.